# reading files: How file pointer is moved using fscanf and how scanf/fscanf work with missing %type

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers

I am really new to file processing in C and I would like to ask several questions!

1. I am using fscanf/fget a lot to convert file into different formats. However I am not very clear about the difference between fscanf and fgets.

In particular, I am not sure whether fscanf() and fgets() will automatically increment the file pointer line by line. From what I understand with testing and documentation, fscanf() only moves the file pointer by 1 character/type at a time; but fgets() seems to read the file line by line(since it terminates when encountered with a newline character). And from documentation, fscanf() will ignore any whitespace characters. So does that mean even though I have a line by line input file, fscanf will fail to read it line by line? Even if I specify the exact formatting, the newline character will not be preserved?

1. With all fscanf/scanf()/sscanf(), I am not sure how the strings are parsed.

In particular, if one line contains 10 non-whitespace parts (word, integer,double, etc), but I only specify 3 of them to be read into variables (using %* or simply don't put anything), what will these read functions do?

For example, my input file looks like this:

```
 9      opls_182         9    DNP      CT       9    0.140     12.0110
10      opls_182        10    DNP      CT      10    0.140     12.0110
11      opls_145        11    DNP      CA      11   -0.115     12.0110   
12      opls_145        12    DNP      CA      12   -0.115     12.0110
```

I only want to read the opls_182 and CT and 9 part (2nd, 5th and 6th column). 
With fgets() and sscanf(), I would write like this:

```
fgets(fp,500,buffer);

sscanf(buffer, "%*s %s %*d %*s %s %d %*f %*f", variables);
or this:
sscanf(buffer, "%*s %s %*d %*s %s %d %*s", variables);
or this:
sscanf(buffer, "%*s %s %*d %*s %s %d", variables);
```

Will these three functions work the same way? So in the second version, will the last %*s parse the entire last two columns, or simply the 2nd last one? (%s seems to start from nonwhite space character to nonwhite space character).

What if I have more specifier than the parts in each line? Will there be an error or the extra variable just stays 0/empty?

And if I used fscanf(), only the first version will work correctly and the 2nd and 3rd version will mess up the reading since fscanf() does not automatically jump line, right?

1. This question pertains to a pattern line: [ bonds ] 387

All the format specifiers in scanf functions will ignore whitespace characters. However, if I want to skip the first part ([ bonds ]) and read the last integer, is there any way to do something like %*some_format %d (ignoring until find the integer)? Will %[^format] work? I tried %[^%d] or %[^d], either will just stop at the character "d" and gives "[ bon". I know you can specify the number of character to be excluded with %[^], however, if the number is changing across the file, this method cannot be used.

1. Will the scanf be able to differentiate different formats if all the parts are connected together without spaces. example: 9opls_182DNPCT91.40STUI8. Can a pattern %d%s%d%s%f%s%d read out: 9, opls_, 182, DNPCT, 91.40, STUI, 8?

I found the reading/writing function in C very powerful but it is also tricky to get right. Thank you guys so much!

Comment: note that this question has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: Using `fscanf` for anything serious is probably not a good idea. For example, using `%d` or `%f` causes undefined behaviour for certain input files, and you don't want a situation where your program can be broken by a carefully crafted input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The rule is very simple: `fgets()` reads an entire line, unless the length of the line exceeds the provided buffer, in which case it reads as much as it can. `fscanf()`, on the other hand, reads what you tell it to, skipping the preceding whitespace. For example, given a line `"1 2 3"` (without quotes), `fgets()` will read the whole line, while `fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &i1, &i2)` will read two integers and store them to the provided addresses, and leave `" 3"` (note included whitespace) unread.
2. In the 2nd `sscanf()` invocation, the last `%*s` parses only the 2nd to last column. Use something like `%*[^\n]` if you want to skip everything until the end of line. You are correct that if you used `fscanf`, only the first version would do what you want, since `fscanf()` treats newline as just another whitespace. Still, you could fix the `fscanf()` version using the `%*[^\n]` format specifier.
3. There is no way for `scanf` to "search" for input, it must always parse it according to the specified format. There is no format equivalent to a `.*` regular expression.
4. Your `scanf` invocation will not do what you want because the first instance of `%s` will eat the remaining string, so only two format characters will be processed. However, if you replace `%s` with `%[^0-9]`, it will do exactly what you want (for this input).

Comment: The behaviour of any `[ ]` content involving `-` is implementation-defined.